# twitter bootstrap carousel link directly to a specific slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap carousel on my website to display a set of images. i am wondering if it is possible to allow a link to link to a specific slide in the carousel. So out of 10 slides a user can click a link to go directly to say slide 5 from a href link.

Is this possible with bootstrap carousel or am i barking up the wrong tree?

*EDIT*

Hi, so i have added the following to my javascript under document.ready function.

However typing in the url `www.example.com/models.php/5` doesnt do anything.
Am i doing something wrong?

```
var url = window.location.href;
var slide = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // 4
goToSlide(slide);

function goToSlide(number) {
    $("#MyCarousel").carousel(number);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### The JavaScript-free way

You can use [`data-slide-to` attribute](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-4) for this, which accepts 0-based indexes represents the slide number.

> Use data attributes to easily control the position of the carousel. `data-slide` accepts the keywords `prev` or `next`, which alters the slide position relative to its current position. Alternatively, use `data-slide-to` to pass a raw slide index to the carousel `data-slide-to="2"`, which shifts the slide position to a particular index beginning with `0`.

Just add an attribute to your anchor, and off you go.

```
<a href="#" data-slide-to="5">Go to slide #5</a>
```

*Thanks to [Cawas's comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611973/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-link-directly-to-a-specific-slide/20612083#comment53984459_20612083) and [Jonas's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611973/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-link-directly-to-a-specific-slide/20612043#20612043).*

---

#### The old-school JavaScript way

You need to use the `.carousel(number)` function.

> .carousel(number)
>
> Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an
>   array).

Check out the [bootstrap docs.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-4)

To be more specific;

Create a javascript function to call, it should look like this :

```
function goToSlide(number) {
   $("#carousel").carousel(number);
}
```

And then, just add an onClick event on your link.

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:goToSlide(5);">Go to slide #5</a>
```

---

#### Getting the slide info from the URL

The source link is `www.example.com/models.php/4`

You could check the url on `document.ready`, and if there's some data at the end of the url, you simply invoke your goToSlide function.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var slide = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // 4

// Remove the trailing slash if necessary
if( slide.indexOf("/") > -1 ) { 
    var slideRmvSlash = slide.replace('/','');
    slide = parseInt(slideRmvSlash);
}
goToSlide(slide);
```

Comment: So how would this be implemented. For example if a user clicks a link on a href link like www.example.com/models.php/4 from a external site which would link to slide 4 on the carousel? Im kind of confused at how this could be implemented. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question, it still doesnt work. Am i doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 but a minor remark: better use unobtrusive markup like `<a href="#" data-slide="5">...</a>`, then write the handler in js like `$("[data-slide]").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... });`.

Comment: @moonwave99 Thank you, please feel free to edit the answer for further improvement!

Comment: While I agree with @moonwave99 (too bad he didn't improve the answer, at least yet) and although using `<a href>` has nothing to do with the question, there's a further and maybe coincidentally (looks like @moon haven't noticed it) related optimisation step there, which I realised [thanks to Jonas down there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20612043/274502): for the `a href` we can just use `data-slide="next"` or in this case `data-slide=2` with no further javascript needed. It's on [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Comment: Thank you very much, Cawas. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

> Use data attributes to easily control the position of the carousel. `data-slide` accepts the keywords `prev` or `next`, which alters the slide position relative to its current position. Alternatively, use `data-slide-to` to pass a raw slide index to the carousel `data-slide-to="2"`, which shifts the slide position to a particular index beginning with `0`.

Comment: Thank you, Jonas, i'm adding this to my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Seçkin's answer, I had to perform two small string operations to make my `slide` string usable. These two mods let the `goToSlide` function correctly parse external links.

Strip trailing slash from url. (My site's web server inserts the slash.)

```
var slideRmvSlash = slide.replace('/','');
```

Convert to an integer

```
var slideInt = parseInt(slideRmvSlash);
```

It worked fine after that.

```
goToSlide(slideInt)
```

Comment: Hey, I'm glad i've been helpful! I'm updating my answer as well.