# How to call a JS Function from View(cshtml file) for going to a specific slide in Bootstrap carousel Control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a view, which contains a Bootstrap Carousal control.
2. There is a 'askaQuestion' button at the View, which looks like this:

   `<button id="btnAskQuestion" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-url="@Url.Action("SendMessage", "Messages", new { category = @note.PageName, patientId = @note.PatientId, appointmentId = Model.AppointmentId, Index = noOfForms }) ">"Ask A Question"</button>`

Basically on click of this button(this button is visible only on specific slides of the carousel, not on all slides),I am redirecting the User to a different Controller/Action method and again as a result of user interaction on that page, again he is coming back to the same page.

Now my intention is to land the user on the same carousal slide from where he clicked the 'askaButton' and not force him to start again from the first slide.To do that I am persisting the last variable, i.e.,Index ; but I am not just not able to land him on the same slide.

I have tried couple of diff approaches:

1. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611973/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-link-directly-to-a-specific-slide) approach, but not sure when to call the Javascript function `goToSlide()`.
2. At the time of loading of the view, was trying to make class="active" for that specific slide, like below. In the `ViewBag.index`, I have persisted the last slide number, from where I had clicked the `askAQuestion` button.

   `<ol class="carousel-indicators">
       @for (int slideCount = 0; slideCount < @formCount; slideCount++)
       {
           if (@formCount == 1)
           {
               <li data-target="#divFormCarousel" data-slide-to="@slideCount" class="active"></li>
           }
           else
           {
               if (ViewBag.index == 0 || ViewBag.index == null)
               {
                   <li data-target="#divFormCarousel" data-slide-to="@slideCount"></li>
               }
               if (ViewBag.index != 0 && ViewBag.index != null && slideCount == ViewBag.index)
               {
                   <li data-target="#divFormCarousel" data-slide-to="@slideCount" class="active"></li>
               }
           }
       }
   </ol>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the carousel's class attribute and explicitly initialize it with `$('#carouselId').carousel()` within your own `$(document).ready(function() {})` handler.  Immediately afterwards, issue the `$("#carouselId").carousel(number)` to go to the specific slide.

Comment: See, when it is landing back to the same page again(after routing through different Controller-Action-View altogether), I can still persist the ViewBag value of Last Slide Number; but the problem is:How to  access this ViewBag value inside JQuery/Javascript?

Comment: ok, I am able to access the ViewBag value inside javascript like this:                  $(document).ready(function () {
        var slideNumber = '@ViewBag.index';
        $("#divPatientFormCarousel").carousel(parseInt(slideNumber));
    });  But now the problem is SInce we are calling this after the DOM is ready for a fraction of sec the user can still see that his carousel is getting created on the page and the first slide and then automatically redirected to the specific slide.Is there any way that I can directly land him to the specific slide without the tiny second glitch?

Comment: Not without modifying the bootstrap carousel source code.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted as it solves the issue to the extent that the bootstrap library is capable.